# Fixing counterexamples from IrisInConfigurationSpace

Tags: drake

I've generated a bunch of supposedly collision free regions using IrisInConfigurationSpace, but upon using them, I've discovered some collision counter-examples. I have an idea for automatically fixing these counterexamples, but I'm wondering if the Drake team might be thinking of better ways. Here is my idea.

1. Using the IrisOptions' prog_with_additional_constraints(), add in the faulty hpoly, either with hpoly.AddPointInSetConstraint, or a manual linear constraint using the hpoly.A() and hpoly.b() matrices.
2. Add an additional half-space constraint to separate the discovered counterexample.
3. Find the largest inscribed ellispoid in this new region, and add that as the initial ellipsoid in IrisOptions.
4. Kick off a new IrisInConfigurationSpace run, with these IrisOptions.

Since the volume of the region should actually shrink, I think I should actually scale this initial ellipsoid by 0.001 or something to prevent prematurely triggering the termination thresholds. If I understand correctly, only the shape of the ellipsoid matters for IrisInConfiguration space adding new hyperplanes.

Does this work? Is there a better way?

Comment: An alternative would be to add a new option to IrisOptions that would allow you to explicitly supply counter-examples. That seems very reasonable, and would be more direct.

I agree that only the shape of the starting_ellipsoid matters.  (So I don't believe that you even need to scale by 0.001; it shouldn't matter).